# SQL - store the result of an inner join in a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code:

```
`SELECT * 
FROM dbo.CSP
JOIN dbo.Check111
ON dbo.CSP."Obs Date (yyyy-MM-dd)"=dbo.Check111."Obs Date (yyyy-MM-dd)";`
```

How can i store it in a new table?

Using this code:

```
insert into NEW_TABLE(
att1, att2, att3...
)

(SELECT * 
FROM dbo.CSP
JOIN dbo.Check111
ON dbo.CSP."Obs Date (yyyy-MM-dd)"=dbo.Check111."Obs Date (yyyy-MM-dd)")
```

Isn't working..

Comment: What database are you using?  Tag appropriately.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would use `into`:

```
SELECT csp.**
INTO new_table
FROM dbo.CSP JOIN
     dbo.Check111
     ON dbo.CSP."Obs Date (yyyy-MM-dd)"=dbo.Check111."Obs Date (yyyy-MM-dd)";
```

You can only use `insert` if you have already created the table and just want to insert new rows.

Comment: That's what i tried, i let it run for 20 minutes (the table has about 10K rows to join). I then stopped the query, tried to get the first 2 rows of `new_table` and got back nothing.. as if the table is empty

Comment: @gambit20088 . . . You have to let the query finish.  This is often done as a single transaction, and when you kill the query everything is rolled back.

Comment: Oh ok i didn't know (pretty new to SQL), i'll try, thanks!